# Compile a WinCE app as a PC app in VS2005

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

anyone knows a way how to compile a WinCE app as a PC app in VS2005. I want to change a standard MFC smart device app to an mfc windows app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to design your application to achieve this from the beginning.

We use our own framework (built directly on top of Win32) and have a single vcproj and sln that targets multiple platforms including Windows Mobile and Win32 on the desktop...

So I can vouch that it is achievable. The catch is that I had to hand code our vcproj files ;) Microsoft don't permit it in the wizards...

Apparently MFC on CE is a lot closer to the desktop equivalent now, so that might make it a lot easier.